# How to calculate years of experience from date_of_hiring to till date in months of an employee using sql query

Tags: oracle

How to calculate years of experience from date_of_hiring to till date in months of an employee using sql query

Comment: which SQL? MSSQL or MySQL, or others?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are typically highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In Postgres you would simply use `current_date - date_of_hiring` to get the number of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, You can use the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function with `TRUNC` and `MOD` function as follows:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      TRUNC(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DATE '2014-08-08')) / 12) YEARS,
>   3      MOD(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DATE '2014-08-08')), 12) MONTHS,
>   4      TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DATE '2014-08-08')) TOTAL_MONTHS
>   5  FROM DUAL;
>
>      YEARS     MONTHS TOTAL_MONTHS
> ---------- ---------- ------------
>          5          6           66
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: i want total experience in months not in combination of years and months

Comment: Ok, refer the updated answer `TOTAL_MONTHS` represents what you need

Comment: with months_between i got answer... Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you. If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm) and then divide it by 12

```
SELECT (MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))/12) "Years" FROM DUAL\\
```

Comment: Did you look at the link on how to use it?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Example :  `SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff;`

Else you have to provide more information about what sql you are using.Datediff should work with MySql and MSSQL based on my experience.

Comment: oracle not mysql or MSSQL

Comment: ya i changed it.sorry for that. i forgot to add

Comment: I updated my answer, tested it. Seem to work. Hope you can use it in your solution

Comment: with months_between i got answer... Thanks

Comment: No worries. I do not understand why my answer was not the correct one though since I answered way before. Oh well.
Would be nice with an upvote anyways to not be in the red.